# what is significance of proxy id while configuring site to site vpn tunnel . why we should use proxy id and in which scenarios

Tags: vpn, networking, site-to-site

i came know about proxy id configuration for first time. when iam troubleshooting site to site vpn tunnel configuration along with vendor . post configuring proxy id issue got resolved . But iam still in confusion why this proxy is used and in which scenario it should be used .

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Proxy-ID* is an IKE option for phase 2 of IPsec. The end points either use the source/destination IP addresses or a proxy-ID for identification (especially when one side has a dynamic address). Both sides need to agree on the parameters.